# Understanding Bubble / Insertion sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Okay, I am out of touch from these school theories but i am trying to refresh myself. I read the algorithm and implemented it. Here is the code

```
public int[] bubbleSort(int[] array)
{
    int swap_bucket;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[j])
            {
                swap_bucket = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = swap_bucket;
            }
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

And here is InsertionSort

```
public int[] InsertionSort(int array[])
{
    int swap_bucket;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for (int k = i; ((k > 0) && (array[k] < array[k-1])); k--)
        {
            swap_bucket = array[k];
            array[k] = array[k-1];
            array[k-1] = swap_bucket;
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

To me, both looks same. I am comparing each element and the moment I find it, I swap it.. but it looks like both implementations are more or less same. Did I code it wrong?

Comment: I think your implementations are correct. Bubble sort and insertion sort are naturally similar, in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, In my opinion you coded Insertion sort wrong.. Check the implementation on [Insertion Sort](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/InsertionSort.htm)

Comment: Hint: How does your insertion sort involve inserting?

Comment: Derek Banas on youtube made [a great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUOyKSZScW0) about these that you may want to check out. Source is available in the description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, In my opinion you coded Insertion sort wrong.

Check the implementation on [Insertion Sort](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/InsertionSort.htm)

**Bubble Sort**: In Bubble sort In an iteration we compare the element with all other elements and if condition( < or > ) is true then we swap the element

whereas

**Insertion Sort**: In an iteration in Insertion sort we compare the element in focus with other elements and place it at its correct location in the sorted part of the array.

**Hint**: Looking into both the algorithms and seeing when the swap is being done will help you understand the difference better.